# learnyounode: juggling async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to solve the Juggling Async problem of [learnyounode](https://nodeschool.io/).

The following is what I have tried. But I am not getting desired output. I can find the solution by searching in google. But what I want is to learn node fundamentals. Can somebody direct me where I am going wrong?

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');
var output = [];
var cnt = 0;

for (var i in process.argv) {
  if (i > 1 ) {
    http.get(process.argv[i],function(response){
      response.pipe(bl(function(err,data){
        output[cnt] = data.toString();
        cnt++;
        if (output.length === (process.argv.length - 2)) {
          printResult(output);
        }
      }));
    });
  }
}

function printResult(output){
  for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    console.log(output[i]);
  }
}
```

The output I am getting:

> 1. ACTUAL:    "Gutful of brickie where shazza got us some ripper. Come a bunyip with watch out for the dinky-di. You little ripper
>      rotten mate lets get some larrikin. "
> 2. EXPECTED:  "Gutful of brickie where shazza got us some ripper. Come a bunyip with watch out for the dinky-di. You little ripper
>      rotten mate lets get some larrikin. "
> 3. ACTUAL:    "Watch out for the aerial pingpong when she'll be right aussie rules footy. He hasn't got a battler mate lets throw a battler.
>      "
> 4. EXPECTED:  "Built like a feral no worries stands out like a bonzer. Come a grundies my flat out like a boardies. As dry as a
>      mokkies no worries shazza got us some rock up. "
> 5. ACTUAL:    "Built like a feral no worries stands out like a bonzer. Come a grundies my flat out like a boardies. As dry as a
>      mokkies no worries shazza got us some rock up. "
> 6. EXPECTED:  "Watch out for the aerial pingpong when she'll be right aussie rules footy. He hasn't got a battler mate lets throw a battler.
>      "
> 7. ACTUAL:    ""
> 8. EXPECTED:  ""

Comment: You should probably include the desired output in your question.

Comment: What's the desired output and what are you getting instead?

Comment: @JoeClay output added.

Comment: @Soviut, Please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember the problem correctly you have to print the responses in the same order as the URLs are provided in the command line argument.

The issue with your solution is that you are not actually storing your responses in correct order.
This part of your code:

```
// ...
output[cnt] = data.toString();
cnt++;
// ....
```

You fired three `http` request asynchronously and you are saving the response in `output` array using the counter `cnt`. Since response can arrive in any order there is no guarantee that the responses will be saved in the same order as the request were fired. For example if response for the Request 3rd came first it will be stored at index `0` in `output` array which is not what you want.

To fix this problem instead of using independent counter. Use the existing variable `i` which was used to fire the http requests. So for request 1 response will be saved at index 0, for request 2 response will be saved at index 1 and so on.

Write you http get request in separate function and pass the index `i` and use this index `i` to save your responses.

```
//....
for (var i in process.argv) {
    if (i > 1) {
        httpGet(i);
    }
}


function httpGet(index) {
    http.get(process.argv[index], function(response) {
        response.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
            output[index - 2] = data.toString();
            cnt++;
            // Use cnt to decide if all the responses have arrived and then print
            if (cnt === (process.argv.length - 2)) {
                printResult(output);
            }
        }));
    });
}
// .....
```

http get request needs to wrapped in a separate function otherwise, the value of variable `i` inside the anonymous function of response block will be same for each functions (which will be `4` in this case). This is classic closure problem. I suggest you to read these to get the detailed explanation:

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

[Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. but the variable 'i' remains 4 each time and not getting saved as desired by applying your changes.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi You are right. It's closure problem. I've updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: _http get request needs to wrapped in a separate function otherwise, the value of variable i inside the anonymous function of response block will be same for each functions_. A gem of an answer. You just rock. And thanks for the links/answer.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Glad, I could help. :)